# How do I detect if a device has a gyroscope in a web browser?

Tags: javascript, mobile, 3d, accelerometer, gyroscope

I am using THREE.js and creating a web-app where the user can rotate the device and the scene will move accordingly. Something similar to [this](https://va3c.github.io/three.js/examples/misc_controls_deviceorientation.html).

I am having a problem differentiating between devices that have a gyroscope and those that don't.

Detecting devices that don't have orientation sensors at all is easy. All the alpha, beta, gamma values of DeviceOrientationEvent are null. But, if a mobile device doesn't have a gyro, it still gives **alpha**, **beta**, **gamma** values in **DeviceOrientationEvent**. The problem is these values are very noisy, and cause a lot of **shaking** in the scene. So, I want to disable the device orientation for these devices. But, so far I haven't been able to find how to make out if the data is coming from a gyro or accelerometer (that's my guess on where the data is coming from).

I don't know if it helps, but a good example of how this is handled can be seen [here](http://krpano.com/tours/paris). (Press the axis like icon at the bottom; you'll have to see it on a device that doesn't have a gyroscope and a gyroscope to see the difference). What they are doing for devices without a gyroscope is only updating the ***pitch*** and the ***roll***. The ***yaw*** isn't updated when you rotate with the phone.

So, it is definitely possible, but I haven't yet found out how even after searching a lot. It would be great if anyone could help.

Thanks a lot.

## EDIT:

On devices that just have an accelerometer, like *MOTO E*, all values are null - **DeviceOrientationEvent** and **rotationRate** - with the only exception of **accelerationIncludingGravity**. But, the device I was testing earlier, that didn't have a gyro but still gave alpha, beta, gamma values for **DeviceOrientationEvent**, seems to have **2** accelerometers according to [the "sensors" details on GSM Arena](http://www.gsmarena.com/motorola_moto_g_(3rd_gen)-7247.php). That is how I suspect it was able to give DeviceOrientationEvent data, albeit *noisy*. Looks like 2 accelerometers aren't enough to give rotation rate ;)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you want to check if gyroscope is present or not, check the parameters that only gyroscope can measure. For example rotation rate is something only gyroscope measures.

Have a look at an example code which says whether gyroscope is present or not:

```
var gyroPresent = false;
window.addEventListener("devicemotion", function(event){
    if(event.rotationRate.alpha || event.rotationRate.beta || event.rotationRate.gamma)
        gyroPresent = true;
});
```

Hope this helps!

### EDIT:

Just a small note: Here, the **DeviceMotionEvent** is used because the rotationRate (and acceleration etc.) can be accessed from this event only. The OP had tried only the DeviceOrientationEvent, so this is worth a mention.

Comment: Wow! That worked wonders... :D Thanks a lot! I didn't think of checking any other event.
I couldn't find anything on the internet to solve this. Thanks again.

Answer (score -1):

Modern solution:

```
if (window.DeviceOrientationEvent) {
  // gyro exist
}
```

[source](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/native-hardware/device-orientation/)

Comment: It's not working. Try this inside your desktop browser which doesn't have any gyroscope. You will get true.